# Global enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Ok say I want to define a terrain enum as

```
enum terrain {MOUNTAIN, GRASS};
```

or something.

How would I make this enum something that is defined in all the classes in my project?

Comment: Put it in a header file that you include.

Comment: Say I want the enum to be defined across multiple classes, would I have to redefine it for every class?

Comment: Prefer `class enum`s over "plain" `enum`s for C++11

Comment: @Alper: `enum class` would be better still.

Answer (score 11):

Put your `enum` declaration in a header file:

### terrain.h

```
#ifndef TERRAIN_H
#define TERRAIN_H

enum terrain {MOUNTAIN, GRASS};

#endif
```

(The `#ifndef`/`#define` pair is an *include guard*, you can read about those elsewhere.)

### source.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "terrain.h"

// your code here
```

Include the `terrain.h` file in every source file where you need it. You can also include a header from another header file if you need to.

Comment: `"You can also include a header from another header file if you need to."` OP, please take this advice very carefully. Strong emphasis on 'if you **need** to'. Avoid including headers in headers when unnecessary.