# Unable to Intialize Enum Class Types | Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, enum-class, scoped-enums

Consider an enum class

```
enum class FOO
{
  A,B,C
};

struct something
{
  FOO abc = FOO::A; //Compiler Doesnt like this
}

int main(){
  something _something;
  return 0;
}
```

So the compiler doesnt like the initialisation and gives me 3 different errors.

**Error    C2238    unexpected token(s) preceding ';'**

**Error    C2059    syntax error: '='**

**Error    C2653    'FOO': is not a class or namespace name**

---

Compiler:

**Visual C++**

**Build Tools MsVC142**

So am I initialisation the enum incorrectly? or am i completely missing something.

Comment: Works on my machine. Can we see some context around it.

Comment: @WalleyM, Keeping the above enum class definition in mind. The enum is being initialized inside a struct so something like. 

struct something
{
   FOO foo = FOO::A;
}

Comment: Where do you put this snippet of code, and how do you compile it?

Comment: Cannot [reproduce](https://www.godbolt.org/z/WfhqT8q17), please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Try putting your enum in a header file. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813750/global-enum-in-c

Comment: Do you happen to compile with a pre C++11 standard? `enum class` was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Edited the question, you can find the MIE there.

Comment: @Timo Compiling it with C++ 14

Comment: @WalleyM not really sure how that's relevant?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of your struct definition `};`.

Comment: Please post a [mre] including the full compiler output, not the errors from the error window